# issue with jquery-ui and helper/ghost blocking elements identity

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

the code below is a standard `resizable()` **jQuery-ui** Widget.

how is it possible to know what is the object it being dragged on to ?

i have tried to catch it using the `clientX` and more... but it did not "deliver" the actual element. i have tried without ghost which was inter-fearing in middle of the way to discover what is layed under. though this is not the issue i guess.

```
  $([selector]).resizable({
   //some  featurs/options and then
    resize:
           function (event, obj) {

              var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
              var elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
           } 
  });
```

any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the `x` and `y` of the mouse cursor? During `resize` or at `stop`?

Comment: I don't see an issue. Created test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qut87y7g/

Comment: @Twisty try this please couldnt identify the object https://jsfiddle.net/rbanay/qut87y7g/3/

Comment: It does identify the object, but only when X is 13. I think there is an offset issue, but I am not sure. Is there a reson you are not detecting `mouseover` event on other objects?

Comment: so in this case i will set the margin to >13 till i know what it is, i think it's looking for top left corner...

Comment: @Twisty try something like - option `alsoResize: "#reszbleContainer",` set offset to left little(left=-10 of resizable) , it will pass on top-left target's corner (- created a container wraps the `resizable` - checking it up now)

Answer (score 0):

take a look on the z-index i have applied to resizable div 
i have lowered it conditionally.

so if it is over some other ide'd object, i will then be able to access its properties rather the blocking `resizable` .

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    $('#resz').resizable({
         handles: 'n, s',
         resize:
             function (event, obj) {

                  var H = obj.size.height;
                  var curobj = $(this);
                  var target = curobj;
                  var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY;
                  var elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

                  if (elementMouseIsOver.id != "") //&& elementMouseIsOver.id != this.id) 
                  {
                      curobj.css("z-index", "-1");
                      target = $("#" + elementMouseIsOver.id); //.css('display', 'none');
                      $("#deb").html("found " + target.attr("id") + " at " + target.css("z-index"));
                  }

            }
     });
 });
```